# Generate singular values of a matrix(Gaussian Random) using Quadrant law in python.

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank, python, gaussian, singular-values

I need to generate Gaussian Random Matrices for a given rank and condition number in python.

For a given target condition number K=5, I select the largest singular value sigma_max uniformly at random in the interval [1, 500]. This sets the smallest singular value as sigma_min = sigma_max/K.

The remaining singular values need to be generated from the Quadrant law. Attached is the link to the paper for the reference( theorem 2)
 [On the singular values of Gaussian random
matrices by Jianhong Shen](https://sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379500003220).

I can use SVD and QR decomposition to generate the final matrix.

Here is the code I'm working on in python.

```
rank=5
condn_num = 5(condition number)
sigma_max = np.random.uniform(1,500)
sigma_min = sigma_max / condn_num

U_ = np.random.normal(0, 1, (rows, rank))
q, r = np.linalg.qr(U_)
U = q
V_ = np.random.normal(0, 1, (cols, rank))
q, r = np.linalg.qr(V_)
V = q
final_matrix = U @ s @ V.transpose() 
//s is a diagonal matrix of dimension(rank X rank)
```

I need to populate the diagonal matrix s with the remaining singular values from the Quadrant law mentioned in the paper above.
**Do anybody how this quadrant law is used to generate remaining singular values?**

Comment: There is some maths behind it but it is unlikely that anyone here is going to understand the code.

Comment: I need help with the math part. I can write the code. Thanks

Comment: The paper's Theorem $2$ gives the PDF of $\sigma$ as$$\frac{\beta}{\pi}\sqrt{4N-\beta^2\sigma^2}$$on support $\left[0,\,2\sqrt{N}/\beta\right]$. This so-called quadrant law differs from Wigner's semi-circular distribution in that the PDF plotted against $\sigma$ is only a quarter circle, confined to the first quadrant. Let me know if you need help sampling this distribution.

Comment: For the above method I needed to generate 3 more singular values from the distribution, as the diagonal matrix is rank X rank in dimension and rank =5. so I did the following to get the remaining 3 after finding max and min singular values. v = np.random.uniform(0.0,2.0,(rank-2)) , val = (sigma_max - sigma_min)/2, v = v * val, v=v+sigma_min. To be clear about the code, I generated 3 random numbers uniformly between (0,2) and multiplied them (sigma_max - sigma_min)/2 and added sigma_min.

Comment: I would be very happy if you can help me with sampling the distribution. Thanks again J.G.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know you'd replied because you didn't include @J.G. in your comment. (I don't need to do something analogous for you because this comment is under your question.) $\sigma$ is one Cartesian coordinate of a random point in a first-quadrant radius-$2\sqrt{N}/\beta$ quarter-circle, whose area is uniformly sampled. Circle-sampling methods discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5837572) can be adapted with a modulus-taking step, for one coordinate only; in particular, they address computational speed.

Comment: Thanks, @J.G. Sorry I didn't know how tagging works. I'll try the method mentioned in the link.